# When data grows how to handle the load without increasing the shard size?

Tags: search, elasticsearch, indexing, elastic-stack

Configured a two nodes with one shard and a replica. How to handle when data reaches the maximum limit. Is it possible to add another node to handle data load without increasing the shard size ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, horizontal scaling is possible, you should be able to configure a new node on new or increased hardware, and configure the existing cluster to redistribute the shards to utilize the new node.

Elastic's [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_scale_horizontally.html) on horizontal scaling of an Elasticsearch cluster.

Comment: We can re-distribute the shard but the problem here we are not going to increase the shard numbers. There is only one shard. Is it possible to handle the data load just by increasing the node alone ?